# Is it wrong to assign value by dereferencing pointer to byte array?

Tags: c++

I have a code where I dereference byte array pointer and assign the value to a variable. This worked ok for int and bool, but failed to work for float and double types. So I think there is a general issue I face. I made a sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char Byte;

int main( )
{
    vector<Byte> v(10);
    float f1 = 14.6;
    copy_n((Byte*)&f1, sizeof(float), (Byte*)&v[4]);

    float f2 = v[4];
    float f3 = 0;
    copy_n((Byte*)&v[4], sizeof(float), (Byte*)&f3);
    cout << "f2: " << f2 << " f3: " << f3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`std::copy_n` works as expected, so I have to use it instead of `f2 = v[4]`

```
output: f2: 154 f3: 14.6
```

What is wrong with `f2 = v[4]` construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `float f2 = v[4]` what happens is this: `float f2 = (float) v[4]` where `v[4]` is a `Byte` aka unsigned char. You take that element (just that element) and convert it to float.

```
In v[4] you have the least significant byte of f1,
...
In v[7] you have the most significant byte of f1
```

They are reversed because your system is little-endian.

With `int` it worked because you used a value smaller than 128 and because the system is little-endian. That is v[4] holds the least significant byte of the original `f1`. As with float you ignore the other 3 bytes, but in this case (int smaller than 128) the rest of the bytes are 0 so you don't see any harm.

Comment: I'd change "last byte" to "least significant byte"

Comment: The ending (least-significant byte) is in a little address. Wouldn't that be a little-endian machine?

Answer (score 2):

When doing

```
copy_n((Byte*)&v[4], sizeof(float), (Byte*)&f3);
```

you copied all the four bytes that constituted the float `f1` from the byte buffer back to the float, while when you did

```
float f2 = v[4];
```

you only assign the least significant byte of the original float `f1` whose value will be implicitly converted into a float and assigned to `f2`.

> Is it wrong to assign value by dereferencing pointer to byte array?

It isn't generally, but here it makes little sense since you are trying to extract the float back from the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`f2` is a `float`, `v[4]` is an `unsigned char`.

Thus, you can assign from `v[4]` to `f2`, but that entails a conversion which is *value-preserving*.

As you actually want to extract the bytes of a `float` from `v`, starting at index 4, that's obviously wrong.

With `bool` and `int` you lucked out, as your implementation is little-endian and the value you wanted to copy is smaller than `SCHAR_MAX`.

Your `copy_n`-construct works, as you can always copy any trivially copyable object (like builtin types) from/to a byte-array one `unsigned char` at a time.

Comment: Nice detail on the lucked out part: endianness and `SCHAR_MAX` hiding the issue.